# Rspec returning blank array from class method functioning in prod

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am trying to construct an Rspec suite to test a method 'filter' on my Article class. I know through first hand use that this class method executes perfectly in production, but when running in  rspec it only returns a blank array. Any ideas why this could be?

```
describe '.filter' do
    it 'filters by user' do
      ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT) if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
      user1 = User.create!(username: 'user1', status: 1)
      article1 = Article.create!(user_id: user1.id)
      Article.filter({writer: 'user1'}).should == article1
    end
  end
```

This is the class filter for Article.

```
def self.filter(hash)
    # need to make case insensitive
    hash.delete_if {|k,v| v == ""}
    hash[:writer_type] = (hash[:writer_type]) if hash[:writer_type] != nil
    sql_base = "select distinct articles.* from articles
       join tags
       on tags.article_id = articles.id
       join categories
       on tags.category_id = categories.id
       left outer join itineraries
       on itineraries.article_id = articles.id
       left outer join cities
       on itineraries.city_id = cities.id
       join users
       on users.id = articles.user_id"

    condition_array = []
    key_array = []
    hash.each_key {|key| key_array << key}
    key_array.each_with_index do |key, i|
      operator = "and"
      operator = "where" if i == 0
      case key
      when :writer
        sql_base << "\n#{operator} users.username like ?"
        condition_array << hash[:writer]
      when :writer_type
         sql_base << "\n#{operator} users.status in (?)"
        condition_array << hash[:writer_type]
      when :city
        sql_base << "\n#{operator} cities.name like ?" 
        condition_array << hash[:city]
      when :category
        sql_base << "\n#{operator} categories.name like ?"
        condition_array << hash[:category]
      end
    end
    sql_array = [sql_base,condition_array].flatten
    articles = Article.find_by_sql(sql_array)
    articles
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `:username` isn't a parameter to that method.  I see `:writer` though, maybe this?

```
describe '.filter' do
  it 'filters by user' do
    ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT) if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    user1 = User.create!(username: 'user1', status: 1)
    article1 = Article.create!(user_id: user1.id)
    expect(Article.filter({writer: user1.username})).to eql([article1])
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I miswrote that- it doesn't work with :writer as the parameter, unfortunately.

Comment: Not sure then.  I see a lot of joins in that SQL, but only a couple objects created for the test.  Throw some debug queries into the spec and see if what you think is in the database actually is...